# ddms null exception after emulator is started

Tags: android, emulation

I am experiencing a problem with android emulator as described @
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986202/exception-after-starting-emulator-ddms-null
Can someone help me ??

Here is snippet of the URL:

After I start the emulator or AVD, in the eclipse Console window I see:

> [2010-10-21 14:03:46 - ddms]Exception
>   during activity from Selector.
>   [2010-10-21 14:03:46 - ddms]null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.accept(Debugger.java:151)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.accept(Debugger.java:125)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.acceptNewDebugger(MonitorThread.java:481)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processDebuggerActivity(MonitorThread.java:455)
>   at
>   com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:266)

The message is continuously printed and my system nearly hangs. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the following message in [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/android-developers/c/c8bsC5Tm3mY) in the [Android Developers](https://groups.google.com/g/android-developers/) Google Group:

> This can happen when a process is terminated on the device and ddms attempts to close its connection to it.
>
> You can safely ignore this exception, this is purely on the ddms side, and has no impact on your processes running on the device.
>
> The fix has already been implemented and will be part of the next release."

Comment: this still seems to be an issue. I am getting 2 messages per second printed on my console. it's printed a few hundred times till now and still counting.

Comment: I get this same error message today after complete running a UI test case.

Comment: @ChuckZHB Same thing here recently.